# Swift package manager in React Native project

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-ios

In iOS, React Native support CocoaPods for Objective-C and Swift code.

Is there any way to bring 3rd party libraries via Swift Package Manager?

Answer (score 2):

You can perfectly add SPM to iOS project inside your React Native solution.
Treat it as a common iOS dependency.
You can present any viewControllers from `rootViewController`